# service not visible when launched inside class

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to implement a service in which the callback is a member function of a class (with reference to the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)))

My code, as below, builds and runs without error, outputting the expected "service launched!". Without using `static` in the callback signature I get `error: invalid use of non-static member function pointsCallback);`

But when I run `rosservice list` "test_service" or "X/test_service" isn't present. Why isn't my service visible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include "image_transform/TransformPoints.h"

class ImageTransform {
 public:
    ImageTransform() {
        ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~");
        ros::ServiceServer service = private_nh.advertiseService("test_service",
                                                                 pointsCallback);
        std::cout << "service launched!" << std::endl;
    }

    static bool pointsCallback(image_transform::TransformPoints::Request &req,
                               image_transform::TransformPoints::Response &res) {
        std::cout << "service called" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // ROS NODE INIT
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_tranform");
    ImageTransform image_transform;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358744/service-not-visible-when-launched-inside-class./) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `service` object is a local variable in the constructor. When the constructor ends it will be destroyed and the service will no longer be provided by the node. It should instead be a member variable of the `ImageTransform` class.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2020-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2020-08-06**:
ah yeah, school boy error. thankyou.